# Is it correct to simplify common verbs in an ordered sentence?

Tags: verbs, sentence-patterns, repetition

Today, I came across a sentence pattern in a well-accepted technical document, as follows:

> Their X1 are too A1, their X2 too A2, and their X3 too A3.

Is it correct to use only one *are* in this kind of sentences? Is it applicable for all verbs? Also, what is the English grammar topic that includes this kind of sentences?

Comment: Yes, one will serve all those that follow.

Comment: Kris is probably right, but without an example of a real sentence or of a surrounding explanation of the actual context it is hard to be sure.

Comment: It's called [*ellipsis*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ellipsis).